# How to strikethrough an li marker

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to `strikethrough` an li element including the li marker itself. On hover I want to add a strikethrough that spans through the entire li element including the `li::marker` itself.

Whenever I add `strikethrough` to the `<li>` element it only adds strikethrough to the content and ignores the `li::marker`.

I've tried applying the striketrhough on the marker with the code below, but that didn't work.

```
li::marker:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

---

```css
li:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

li::marker:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foobar</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: FWIW, your selector for the marker on hover is incorrect; it should be `li:hover::marker`.  Unfortunately, however, even with the selector corrected the rules applied will not achieve the desired result.

Comment: You are using `<ol>` or `<ul>`? Will the list wrap text?

Comment: @CBroe — my only evidence is observation— if you give it some obvious style rule (such as `color: red`) I do _not_ see the style applied for the selector `li::marker:hover` but I _do_ the the style applied when I update it to `li:hover::marker` (at least this is the case on my machine) [Here is an example showing what I mean](https://codepen.io/awnied/pen/zYeLwRx).

Comment: @AlexanderNied you're correct, order appears to be important here. Not sure what context I was thinking of (probably only pseudo classes, not pseudo elements.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **UPDATE**

**DO NOT USE THIS SOLUTION!!!**

As I expected, a much better, more elegant solution exists than the trash I provided below; [check out LS_'s answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77555253/6831341).  In my opinion, his answer deserves to be marked as "selected".

---

### **(Original answer)**

What I've provided below is a hacky, absolutely filthy solution that achieves the result by wrapping the content in a relatively positioned `<span>`, and on giving it extra leading spaces on hover while simultaneously adjusting it's position to the left.  I can't even promise it will work consistently across platforms.  It's gross, and I pray that somebody provides a better solution and that don't have to use this approach.

```css
li span {
  position: relative;
}

li:hover span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  left: -1em;
}

li:hover span::before {
    content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Foo</span></li>
  <li><span>Bar</span></li>
  <li><span>Foobar</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [list-style-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position). Example:

```css
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}


li:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foobar</li>
</ol>
```